# Why python requests always return 401 on iMac?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to verify whether resources are there in page source code. User should login first to go through the website. And all resources getting are binded with cookies.
I get cookies through selenium webdriver.get_cookies().

It's weird my requests.get(url, cookies) returns 200 on Windows while returning 401 on iMac. The below is my script:

```
dictCookies = driver.get_cookies()
jsonCookies = json.dumps(dictCookies)
with open('cookies.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    listCookies = json.load(f1.read())

mycookie = {
    'userName': 'listCookies[0]['value']',
    'token'   : 'listCookies[1]['value']',
    'userId'  : 'listCookies[2]['value']'
}
```

And then I get cookies as below:

```
cookie = {
    'userName': 'test',
    'token'   : 'DE233445DVF4',
    'userId'  : 'amanda'
}
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)
print(r.raise_for_status())
```

It returns requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unthorized for url: url.
Can anybody help this?

Comment: Anybody helps? I'm still getting stuck.

Comment: Anyone helps???